# OCSP response parsing error. Error while BER Decoding

Tags: pdf, adobe, bouncycastle, ocsp

I am trying to add an OCSP Response to a PDF document that I am signing with Bouncy Castle using CmsSignedDataGenerator

I think I'm embedding the OCSP response correctly but when I open the document in Adobe Reader 11 (offline) and check *Signature Properties > Show Signer's Certificate > Revocation > Problems Encountered* I see this error:

> OCSP response parsing error:
>
> Error encountered while BER decoding:

Adobe Reader does not give me any more information on this error and I don't know where to search for. Does anyone know why Adobe is having problems decoding the OCSP response or how can I get more specific information?

[This is the PDF I'm trying to validate.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19520613/hand%20clenching.pdf)

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Many people only insert the BasicOcspResponse, nut the full response. Could that be your issue?

Comment: Thanks for answering @mkl! Are you familiar with BouncyCastle? I think I am inserting the BasicOcspResponse but maybe I am wrong. This is the object I pass as a DerSet to the AttributeTable: ((BasicOcspResp)ocspResponse.GetResponseObject()).GetEncoded(). Is there any other I should know of?

Comment: *I think I am inserting the BasicOcspResponse* - yes, and that is wrong, you need to insert the full response. This is a mistake many have done.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer, sorry. I'll try to insert the full response and see what happens!

Comment: Thanks @mkl, you were right :). My problem was in the way I was formatting the response before inserting it and that I needed to insert the full response. Now I am having this error  _OCSP response signature is invalid_ but I think it is a completely different question

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCSP response is embedded in the OP's signature like this:

```
1705 1920:             SEQUENCE {
1709    9:               OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 840 113583 1 1 8'
1720 1905:               SET {
1724 1901:                 SEQUENCE {
1728 1897:                   [1] {
1732 1893:                     SEQUENCE {
1736 1889:                       SEQUENCE {
1740    1:                         ENUMERATED 0
1743 1882:                         [0] {
1747 1878:                           SEQUENCE {
1751    9:                             OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         :                               ocspBasic (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 48 1 1)
1762 1863:                             OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
1766 1859:                               SET {
1770 1855:                                 SEQUENCE {
1774  286:                                   SEQUENCE {
1778  126:                                     [1] {
1780  124:                                       SEQUENCE {
1782   11:                                         SET {
1784    9:                                           SEQUENCE {
1786    3:                                             OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         :                                               countryName (2 5 4 6)
1791    2:                                             PrintableString 'AU'
         :                                             }
         :                                           }
```

In contrast to my initial idea the OP has not merely tried to include the basic OCSP response but indeed a complete response:

```
1736 1889:                       SEQUENCE {
1740    1:                         ENUMERATED 0
1743 1882:                         [0] {
1747 1878:                           SEQUENCE {
1751    9:                             OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         :                               ocspBasic (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 48 1 1)
1762 1863:                             OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
```

Unfortunately the basic OCSP response encapsulated in that OCTET STRING

```
1766 1859:                               SET {
1770 1855:                                 SEQUENCE {
1774  286:                                   SEQUENCE {
1778  126:                                     [1] {
```

is additionally embedded in a SET which is against the specification ([RFC 2560](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2560) and others):

```
ResponseBytes     ::= SEQUENCE {
   responseType   OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
   response       OCTET STRING }
```

> The value for response SHALL be the DER encoding of
> BasicOCSPResponse.

```
BasicOCSPResponse      ::= SEQUENCE {
  tbsResponseData      ResponseData,
  signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
  signature            BIT STRING,
  certs                [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
```

The OP meanwhile seems to have corrected his way of (re)constructing the complete OCSP response.